# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification not working on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

UIKeyboard will show and hide notification method working fine in iOS8 and later, but it not works in iOS7. Is there any alternative?

My Application Deployment target is iOS7.

My Code is here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(HideKeyboard:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    CGSize kbSize =
        [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    if (!scroll) {
        scrollValue = self.WholeScreenUIView.frame.origin.y - kbSize.height;
    }

    scroll = YES;
}

- (void)HideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)sender
{

    scroll = NO;

    scrollValue = 0.0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on does not work? Does the method get called in iOS 7?

Answer (score -1):

Use this code..

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideHandler:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillshowHandler:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

- (void) keyboardWillHideHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
   [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}

- (void) keyboardWillshowHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+44)];

}
```

Hope this helps.This works in my case

Comment: This code is no different then in question, except that your register the observer code is not place in any method.

Comment: Thanks for your support, Above code works in iOS 8 but It couldn't work in iOS 7.

FYI: The observer function not called in iOS 7